# How to change color of progress bar based of fullness of bar

Tags: android

I have a progress bar indicator, which has current and max volume. And I.need to change color of bar if fullness is under 90% (current /max weight). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change progress bar color at runtime with the following code:

```
final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb);
Drawable progressDrawable = progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable();

if (progressDrawable != null && progressBar.getProgress() < 90) {
    final Drawable mutateDrawable = progressDrawable.mutate();
    DrawableCompat.setTint(mutateDrawable, Color.RED);
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(mutateDrawable);
} else {
    final Drawable mutateDrawable = progressDrawable.mutate();
    DrawableCompat.setTint(mutateDrawable, Color.GREEN);
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(mutateDrawable);
}
```